# How to add simulated values from a poisson distribution for each row and add them into the dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, poisson

I am trying to expand a dataframe by including, for each row, 500 simulated values from a Poisson distribution whose parameter Theta (count_mean) is already stored in the dataframe. In the example below I am only providing a dataframe example, since my real data is composed by more than 50,000 rows (i.e. ids).

```
example.data <- data.frame(id=c("4008", "4118", "5330"), 
                       count_mean=c(2, 25, 11)
                       )
```

So for each row, I know I have to generate the simulated values by:

```
rpois(500, example.data$count_mean)
```

How can I introduce these values into the same dataframe, in which each new column presents one simulated value for each row?

Comment: As @Cettt noted: consider a "long" data format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to simulate the numbers and then use `cbind` to bind your data together:

```
simdata <- t(sapply(example.data$count_mean, function(x) rpois(500, x)))

colnames(simdata) <- paste0("sim_", 1:500)

cbind(example.data, simdata)
```

However, I would encourage you to work with a different data format: maybe a long table would be more appropriate in this situation than the current wide table.

Comment: Great! This helped me doing what I needed, thank you! About the long format, I am not sure whether that will help me because I will conduct further calculations between each generated new column and a vector of single values for each id. Anyways I might try it later after finishing all steps of the desire analysis.

Comment: I actually changed the table to long format and my whole analysis was easier, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
example.data %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(poisson = list(rpois(500, count_mean))) %>%
  unnest(poisson) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(count=row_number()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from="count", names_prefix="sim_", values_from="poisson")
```